# For comparing a calculated value to a fixed precision number, is string conversion better or mathematical calculation?

Tags: javascript

I have the following two scenarios where I want to compare a certain calculated value to float value **0.05**.

In the first scenario, the value is being converted into **String** to get the value in two decimal place and then converting it back into a number for comparison.

```
var soneFunction = function(value)
{
    var a = ((Math.round(value * 10) / 10) - value).toFixed(2);

    if(Number(a) === 0.05)
        a = -0.05;

    return a;
};
```

In the second scenario, I am not doing any string-number conversion but using mathematical functions.

```
var soneFunction = function(value)
{   
    var roundingValue = (Math.round(value * 10) / 10) - value;

    // fix the value till 2 decimal places
    var a = Math.round((roundingValue) * 100) / 100;

    if(a === 0.05)
        a = -0.05;

    return a;
};
```

I am curious to know which one is better?

**UPDATE:**
By better, I meant performance and memory consumption wise.

Comment: Define what means better. Faster? Consumes less memory? Is more understandable for developers? Safer?

Comment: I meant performance and memory consumption wise which is better.

Comment: There are tools to test this, such as [benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/) or [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/). Keep in mind that the results might vary from one JavaScript VM to another. Chrome and node are running off V8, firefox is using SpiderMonkey, MS Edge has Chakra and so on. How you interpret the different results is up to you, you could use the average value, worst value, value weighted by your target distribution etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
let parseFloatWithPrecision = function (value, precision){
    var floatValue = parseFloat(value) || 0.0   ;

    floatValue = floatValue.toFixed(precision);
    return parseFloat(floatValue);
}

let compare = function(val){
    if(parseFloatWithPrecision(val, 2) == 0.05)
        return -0.05;
    return val;
}
```

Comment: So, what you are saying is converting to string and back is better than using mathematical functions?

Comment: yes I believe the mathematical function would induce more precision loss